# replace a whole file with another file in bash

Tags: bash, replace, directory

Ive learned how to replace a line using bash script but I am wanting to learn how to replace a whole file with another file in a different folder with the same name.  Is this possible??

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
cp -f [src file (will be copied)] [dst file (will be overwritten)]
```

Copies the source file and overwrites the destination file (hence `-f` which stands for "force").

Comment: I couldnt get this to process.  Did I miss something or need to end it with done???

Comment: What is the command you are writing?  You don't need the square brackets.

Comment: as a side note, this preserves the original file's mode and ownership when done with sudo

Comment: If you still see a prompt use `which cp` at the command line to check for `cp` alias.

Comment: Looks like you switched up the arguments, It should be the other way around.
`cp -f [new file] [original file]`

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic, agree, if we're looking for replacing scenario using cp [source] [destination], we should define new_file first (as a source that will be used during copy) and original_file as second param (as a file that will contain result of the copy - in our case replacing)

Comment: Your wording of "new" and "original" is misleading. I would suggest instead using "to be copied" and "to be overwritten".

Answer (score 53):

In case you are attempting to copy just the content of the file try

```
cat /first/file/same_name > /second/file/same_name
```

This will overwrite all the content of the second file with the content from the first.  However, your owner, group, and permissions of the second file will be unchanged.

Comment: "overwrite content" and "copy" are kinda different operations if the destination file is a symlink :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to deal with hardlinked files updated in a way the caused the link to be broken (saved as a separate file.)

Answer (score 10):

Use these commands:

```
mv file1 file2
```

If file2 does not exist, then file1 is renamed file2. If file2 exists, its contents are replaced with the contents of file1.

```
mv -i file1 file2
```

Like above however, since the `"-i"` (interactive) option is specified, if file2 exists, the user is prompted before it is overwritten with the contents of file1.

```
mv file1 file2 file3 dir1
```

The files file1, file2, file3 are moved to directory dir1. dir1 must exist or `mv` will exit with an error.

```
mv dir1 dir2
```

If dir2 does not exist, then dir1 is renamed dir2. If dir2 exists, the directory dir1 is created within directory dir2.

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what the OP wants - it moves/renames files, not copies/overwrites them...

Comment: HI @Christian thanks for your comment. Can you please elaborate further? I want to understand why renaming a file isn't the same as replacing. For example, if I want to "replace" file1 with file2, why can't I just do: mv file2 file1 ? Does this command replace if file1 is removed first?

Comment: Renaming a file means it won't exist in the original location - seems to me that what the OP wants is to overwrite a file without any such side effects.

Answer (score 5):

Today I was in need of something same solution, only thing change is I need to replace old version of php file in many users directory with newer version. I'm heading here and just mix match with other stack's answer and solve my issue. I used @joseph code with find command.

I'm sharing my little code here, hope it will help someone.

```
for file in $(find /home/*/ -type f -name 'timthumb.php');
do
    cat /home/timthumb.php > $file;
done
```

Comment: To make sure it works not just with text files, use cp -f, e.g.  
`find -type f -iname myFile | while read fileName; do cp-f ../sourceFileLocation/myFile $fileName; done`  
It will also take file from ../sourceFileLocation/myFile and replace all occurrences in the current dir and subdirs, but is guaranteed to work with binary files. Also personally I prefer `| while read` to `for $()` more often than not.